# Is it possible to insert values into a form being passed through the view

Tags: django, view

My view currently looks like this

```
def EditClientDetails(request):
    obj = RetrieveClientList()
    uname =request.GET.get('uname','')
    return render(request, 'manageClient.html', {'form': MainLoginForm(),}  )
```

What the above view does is that it adds a form object and makes it available to the `manageClient.html` page
Now the `MainLoginForm` looks simple

```
class MainLoginForm(forms.Form):
    user_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    user_address = forms.CharField(required=True)
```

My question is : Is it possible to populate text to the user_address field before doing this in the view

```
return render(request, 'manageClient.html', {'form': MainLoginForm(),}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is way of loading form with initial data

```
 return render(request, 'manageClient.html', {'form': MainLoginForm(initial='user_address':request.user.address),}
```

sure it works on the Model forms.